# copy tables from one database to another using macros in dbt

Tags: macros, jinja2, dbt

What I want to achieve is to copy tables from one database to another using macros in dbt

I created a macro which list my table names from a schema as below

```
{%- macro get_dimension_names(database = target.database, schema = 'dbo', dry_run = True) -%}

 {% set get_tables_query %}

 
   select  distinct table_name
     --- '{{ database | upper }}.' || table_schema ||'.'|| table_name 
    from {{database}}.information_schema.tables
    where table_schema = upper('{{schema}}')
      and table_schema ='DBO'
      and table_type='BASE TABLE'
      
  {% endset %}

{{ log('\nGenerating dimensions list...\n', info=True) }}

 
   {% set get_dimension_names = run_query(get_tables_query).columns[0].values() %}  
  
  -- iterates through the statments generated and executes them if dry_run is false else it just logs the statements
 {% for query in get_dimension_names %}
        {% if dry_run %}
            {{ log(query, info=True) }}
        {% else %}
            {{ log('Generating tables: ' ~ query, info=True) }}
            {% do run_query(query) %} 
        {% endif %}       
    {% endfor %}

{%- endmacro -%}
```

I have another macro which calls the above macro to generate sql select * from the  above list to generate sql statements

```
{%- macro statement_list() -%} ------database = target.database, schema = 'dbo', dry_run = True) -%}

    {% set tables = get_dimension_names() %} --- this is from macro which lists table names

  {{ log('\nGenerating sql statements list...\n', info=True) }}

    {% set query %}

        select *
        from tables
      --  {% if tables -%}
        --    where lower(table_name) in {% for t in tables -%} {{ t }} {%- endfor -%}
      ---  {%- endif -%}
    {% endset %}

  {{ log('\nGenerating query...\n', info=True) }}

    {% set results = run_query(query).columns[0].values() %}   -------.columns[0].values() %}

     -- iterates through the statments generated and executes them if dry_run is false else it just logs the statements
 {% for query in results %}
        {% if dry_run %}
            {{ log(query, info=True) }}
        {% else %}
            {{ log('Generating tables: ' ~ query, info=True) }}
            {% do run_query(query) %} 
        {% endif %}       
    {% endfor %}

{%- endmacro -%}
```

I am getting the below error

```
17:58:25  Encountered an error while running operation: Database Error
  002003 (42S02): SQL compilation error:
  Object 'TABLES' does not exist or not authorized.
```

```
I did change my second macro as below

{%- macro generate_dimension_names(database = target.database, schema = 'dbo') -%}

 {% set get_tables_list %}

-- query to select table names with column __is_row_current as not all tables in dbo have __is_row_current column
   select distinct table_name  
    from {{database}}.information_schema.columns
    where 
      column_name = '__IS_ROW_CURRENT'
      AND table_schema ='DBO'
     -- and table_name  in (  'POSTCODE')
      
  {% endset %}


   {% set get_tables  = run_query(get_tables_list).columns[0].values() %}

   {{return(get_tables)}}
  
 
{%- endmacro -%}


Even though the macro generates create statements, it is throwing an error as below
 Encountered an error while running operation: Database Error
  001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with your code.

1. The one generating the error:

   Your `statement_list` macro contains the following:

   ```sql
   {% set query %}
       select *
       from tables
       ...
   {% endset %}
   ```

   Normally you don't nest curlies in jinja, but in a set block, if you want to template a variable, you need to include the curlies:

   ```sql
   {% set query %}
       select *
       from {{ table }}
       ...
   {% endset %}
   ```
2. In the `statement_list` macro, you're not iterating over the list of tables properly. You need something like this, which will compile to a single string that will have all of your select statements separated by a semicolon:

   ```sql
   {% set query %}
   {% for table in tables %}
       create or replace table destination_schema.{{table}} as (
           select *
           from {{ table }}
           ...
       )
       ;
   {% endfor %}
   {% endset %}
   ```

   Then once you have `query` defined, you just run that single statement (gated by `dry_run` if you want)
3. You don't return anything from your `get_dimension_names` macro. You need to add:

   ```sql
   {% set dimension_names = run_query(get_tables_query).columns[0].values() %}
   {{ return(dimension_names) }}
   ```
4. You need to remove this final block from your `get_dimension_names`, which seems like it belongs in your other macro:

   ```sql
   -- iterates through the statments generated and executes them if dry_run is false else it just logs the statements
   {% for query in get_dimension_names %}
       {% if dry_run %}
           {{ log(query, info=True) }}
       {% else %}
           {{ log('Generating tables: ' ~ query, info=True) }}
           {% do run_query(query) %} 
       {% endif %}       
   {% endfor %}

   {%- endmacro -%}
   ```

Finally, I don't think this is a great approach. If you want to persist a model into a new schema, you can use dbt's [custom schema](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/custom-schemas) model config. If you want them in two places, you should probably use a view (which you can manage as an additional dbt model with a custom schema config) or if on snowflake, a zero-copy clone.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, really appreciate it.